# Element moved using JS/jQuery PIE not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, css3pie

I have moved an element using JS on body load but PIE still have the background of the element visible or in the wrong position. However, on subsequent clicks/interaction that trigger movements/animation, PIE works ok. Why is that? I even tried to use `setTimeout(..., 1200)` to update the element position, but it does not seem to update

I am thinking if there was a `PIE ready` event that I can use to update element position, it will fix it?

```
$masthead.css({top: "-" + ($masthead.outerHeight() - 20) + "px"});
```

Also I notice PIE will place those elements (PIE generated backgrounds etc) in position as if no JS (that changes classname/position) was run. I suspect thats the problem

Comment: perhaps `$(masthead).css({top: ($(masthead).outerHeight() - 20) + "px"});`

Comment: So you changed `$masthead` to `$(masthead)`? I guess u mean `$("#masthead")`? If so actually I did `var $masthead = $("#masthead")` already

Comment: oh, .. i did not know that, is that working in other browser???

Comment: erm without PIE yes the JS works. So its an IE only problem, if I remove PIE it works fine too. Just not CSS3 drop shadows then ...

Comment: well, what is PIE anyway, PIE chart??

Comment: @experimentX, I should have gave a link or something. Its [Progressive Internet Explorer](http://css3pie.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used images for drop shadows instead ... but I think **[PIE.js](http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/)** will work.

```
// after changes by JS
PIE.attach($("elem")[0]);
```